# Push Data Into Array in State Array In Reactjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mern, use-state

**Hello All I hope All Are Doing Well**

I have A **issue** I am **uploading multiple images in Cloudinary** via ReactJs

**Here Is Input Field**

```
         <input
          type="file"
         className="form-control"
         required
         onChange={(e) => setImages(e.target.files)}
          multiple
           />
```

**OnChange I'm storing all files on a state given below**

```
const [images, setImages] = useState([]);
```

Now I am looping the **state** and **uploading each file** to **Cloudinary** and **extracting the URL** of each Image code is given below

```
for (const file of images) {
  async function upload() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("upload_preset", "DummyPreset"); // Replace the preset name with your own
    formData.append("api_key", "0300545648961"); // Replace API key with your own Cloudinary key

    // Make an AJAX upload request using Axios (replace Cloudinary URL below with your own)
    await axios
      .post(
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/Dummycloud/image/upload",
        formData,
        {
          headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        const fileURL = data.secure_url; // You should store this URL for future references in your app
        console.log(fileURL);
     
      });
  }

  upload();
}
```

Here I'm able to extract each link As **fileURL** and consoled it

```
console.log(fileURL);
```

To See The Output Please click the Link it will redirects you to the image  [**Outputimage**](https://res.cloudinary.com/talhakash/image/upload/v1619521751/alyvj7usjpjc6jjqgs4w.png)

As You Can see all URLs Are Extracted Now I want to push All Extracted  URLs into an Array And Wants to send them to Express Server where I'll store them into DB

**Please Let Me Know How Store All URLs into a state array  whenever any URL extracted it'll be stored into That array**

Comment: Use the state hook `const [images, setImages] = React.useState([])` and then update your state with `setImages([...images, fileURL])` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html

Comment: not working broo

Comment: Show us what you tried so we are able to help you further.

Comment: `await axios
      .post(
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/Dummycloud/image/upload",
        formData,
        {
          headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" },
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        const fileURL = data.secure_url;
         setImages([...images, fileURL]);
     
      });
  }

  upload();
}`                                                           **The issue is state is not updating on real time**

Comment: No that can't work. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Here's The Solution**

**Thanks For Contribution**

```
 var ImagesUrlArray = [];
for (const file of image) {

  async function upload() {
     const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("file", file);
formData.append("upload_preset", "DummyPreset"); // Replace the preset name with your own
formData.append("api_key", "0300545648961"); // Replace API key with your own Cloudinary key

// Make an AJAX upload request using Axios (replace Cloudinary URL below with your own)
await axios
  .post(
    "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/Dummycloud/image/upload",
    formData,
    {
      headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest" },
    }
  ).then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        var fileURL = data.secure_url; // You should store this URL for future references in your app
        
        ImagesUrlArray = [...ImagesUrlArray];

        ImagesUrlArray.push(fileURL);

        if (ImagesUrlArray.length === image.length) {
          
          const res = axios
            .post("http://localhost:5000/register", {
              fullname: Data.fullname,
              email: Data.email,
              pass: Data.pass,
              cpass: Data.cpass,
              phone: Data.phone,
              imagee: ImagesUrlArray,
            })
            .then((response) => response);

          setdataa(res);
        }
      });
  }

  upload();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this function returns a Promise
const uploadFile = (file) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append(stuff);
  return axios.post('some/path', formData).then(response => response.data.secure_url);
};
```

```
Promise.all(images.map(uploadFile)).then(fileURLs => storeFileURLs(fileURLs))
```

Comment: @TalhaZubairMayo Show me how you integrated my code snippet into your component and I may be able to help you.